# Decode and encoded date for Android

Tags: android, date

I am not a professional.  I am trying track history on my phone (a Samsung L300) .  I have a dump of the bookmarks (in a folder `\Application Data\Content Providers\bookmarks.xml`). Everything looks pretty straightforward, but the puzzle is the Date code. The thirteen digit date code does not conform to anything I can translate: `1428021441222`. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That's simply a linux epoch, the number of seconds (or here, milliseconds) since January 1, 1970. You can convert it online [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/), or just read it into Date type, such as

```
Date theDate = new Date(1428021441222L);
```

`1428021441222` represents Fri, 03 Apr 2015 00:37:21 GMT.